# ¿Que hace [:-1] en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio:

```
def fun(nombres):
    nombres.insert(1,'Charly')
    nombres=nombres[::-1]

def main():
    names = ['Diego', 'Nicolas', 'Lautaro','Luciano']
    fun(names)
    print(names)


main()
```

Mi pregunta es porque en la siguiente linea `nombres=nombres[::-1]` no da vuelta la lista y una variación del mismo ejercicio que esa linea es reemplazada por `nombres=nombres[:-1]` ..tampoco hace nada..
Que haría en cada caso y porque pasa esto?.

Comment: `[::-1]` si da vuelva a la lista (la invierte) tu problema es que no retornas el valor y eso solo queda en la función `fun` y `[:-1]` sirve para escoger el ultimo elemento de una lista

Comment: @Christian. `[1,2,3][:-1]  => [1, 2]`

Comment: @CandidMoe tienes razón, me confundí con el `[-1]` ._.

Answer (score 3):

El método insert realiza la siguiente instrucción:

```py
fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']

fruits.insert(1, "orange")
```

Output:
`['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'cherry']`

**e indexar con '[::-1]' corresponde a tomar los indices al revés...**, al utilizarlo en el ejemplo anterior correspondería a la siguiente salida: `['cherry', 'banana', 'orange', 'apple']`

Lo que sucede en tu código y la razón por la cual no parece haber cambios en la salida, es que no estás tomando la salida de la función. Al contrario, tomas el mismo valor de la entrada sin modificar.

En el caso de la primera función:

```py
def fun(nombres):
    nombres.insert(1,'Charly') # asignación 'inplace', similar a this.list = ...
    nuevo_nombres=nombres[::-1] # nueva asignación, 'nombres' sería una variable ubicada en distinto espacio de memoria
    return nuevo_nombres
```

Al asignar en una variable distinta en el espacio de memoria requieres usarla explicitamente en return

En la segunda función, el caso es similar:

```py
def main():
    names = ['Diego', 'Nicolas', 'Lautaro','Luciano']
    salida_names=fun(names) # recuperas el valor de salida asignandolo a una nueva variable
    print(salida_names)
```

---

Lo que concluyo es que, si dentro de las funciones utilizas metodos 'inplace', osea, que se ejecuten y cambien valores sin utilizar la asignación con '=' la función que construyes resulta siendo 'inplace' por lo que tampoco tendrías que asignar a un nuevo valor.

Al contrario si usas '=' la dirección de memoria cambia a una nueva y para recuperar denuevo el valor debes asignarlo a un nuevo espacio de memoria.

---

debugg 1:

```py
def fun(nombres):
    nombres.insert(1,'Charly')
    nombres=nombres[::-1] # esta nueva variable a pesar de tener el mismo nombre tiene una direccion de memoria distinta
    return nombres

def main():
    names = ['Diego', 'Nicolas', 'Lautaro','Luciano']
    fun(names)
    print(names)

main()
```

output: `['Diego', 'Charly', 'Nicolas', 'Lautaro', 'Luciano']`
vemos que ejecuta correctamente el agregar a 'Charly' pero no revertir la lista (pues se utiliza '=' para asignar a un distinto espacio de memoria que el de entrada)

debugg 2:

```py
def fun(nombres):
    nombres.insert(1,'Charly')
    nombres=nombres[::-1] # esta nueva dirección
    return nombres # es la misma que se está devolviendo

def main():
    names = ['Diego', 'Nicolas', 'Lautaro','Luciano']
    names=fun(names)
    print(names)

main()
```

output: `['Luciano', 'Lautaro', 'Nicolas', 'Charly', 'Diego']`
En este caso se han ejecutado ambas, pero es necesario recuperar la salida con `names=fun(names)`.

debugg 3:

```py
def fun(nombres):
    nombres.insert(1,'Charly')
    list.reverse(nombres) # hace lo mismo que nombres=nombres[::-1] pero 'inplace' sin utilizar '='

def main():
    names = ['Diego', 'Nicolas', 'Lautaro','Luciano']
    fun(names)
    print(names)

main()
```

En este último caso no se utilizan asignaciones 'out place' con '=', por lo tanto dentro de la función `main()` no necesitas recuperar la salida con '='

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te falto es retornar la variable nombres en la funcion, mira:

```
def fun(nombres):
    nombres.insert(1,'Charly')
    nombres=nombres[::-1]
    return nombres

def main():
    names = ['Diego', 'Nicolas', 'Lautaro','Luciano']
    print(fun(names))

main()
```

Lo que te falto es retornar la variable donde se almacenara la lista
invertida `return nombres`.

En la funcion main te falto imprimir esa funcion cuando lo llamas `print(fun(names))` .

salida:

```
['Luciano', 'Lautaro', 'Nicolas', 'Charly', 'Diego']
```